# What is the relation between Newton's third law and Hooke's law?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring

Is there any relation between the two laws? Because in class has been said that actually Newton's third law is the "simple version" of Hooke's law and thus the Normal force (reaction to Weight force) is just a reaction to a deformation of the ground.

Comment: I believe the confusion is resolved by viewing the pulling of the spring as an increase in potential energy, rather than from the other direction (/side of the equation).

Comment: -1. Not clear what you are asking. Please provide further explanation of what the relation is supposed to be. Hooke's Law is about linearity (force directly proportional to deformation). Newton's 3rd Law says nothing about force being proportional to deformation - it says nothing at all about deformation - and it will still apply if force and deformation are related in any other way - then Hooke's Law does not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The laws are unrelated.

I'd say you either misunderstood your teacher, or they tried to give an intuition/simplification/example that clearly didn't work.